# Jquery ID returns object instead of string

Tags: jquery, attributes

I've got a piece of jQuery code that detects when a  element is changed then returns that element's ID:

HTML:

```
<select name="blah" class="adropdown" id="12345">
<option value="0">Select an option:</option>
<option value="1">test</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.adropdown').change(function(){
    var num = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(num);
});
```

When I change the dropdown, though, instead of alerting the ID it alerts "[object Object]". This should be simple -- any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks,
G

Comment: It should work by all means. Check the rest of the code.

Comment: Problem lies elsewhere? http://jsfiddle.net/3asyB/

Comment: do you assigned ".adropdown" class only to select

Comment: it doesn't - http://jsfiddle.net/R7TYv/

Comment: @MotaBOS HTML5 supports numeric IDs.

Comment: Sorry I accidently removed my comment. Then Greg needs to make sure that he is using HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine for me. 
But i think you have another tag with the same id. So enssured that you have only one elment on the page with id = 12345

Comment: I doubt it may affect the `change` event.

Comment: It's the only element on the page with that ID. It's Name and ID are the same, but that shouldn't be a problem. In my code the ID doesn't begin with a number. This is really frustrating...! Thanks for your answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will alert 12345 always,Becase 'id' is attribute of select tag.

Please use value attribute if you want to alert value of each dropdown.

For e.g:

```
$('.adropdown').change(function(){
var num = $(this).attr('value');
alert(num);
});

<select name="blah" class="adropdown" id="12345">
<option value="0">Select an option:</option>
<option value="1">test</option>
<option value="2">test_1</option>
</select>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to return the ID. The code I posted works, but when it's in place in my (much much longer) code, something's conflicting with it. Just wondering if anyone had any ideas what could cause it.